# Регистрируемый

Tags: стилистика

Как правильно написать предложение:
"Владеет ли супруг(а) регистрируемого дисконтной картой компании?".
Просто оставить "регистрируемого" или добавить "регистрируемого лица, нового члена Клуба"?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Нужно добавить! А то не сразу смысл ясен. Получается что-то вроде "регистрируемого дисконтной картой" Поскольку регистрируемый - причастие, следующие за ним слова воспринимаются как зависимые от него. Да и официально-деловой стиль предполагает ясность, четкость, однозначность формулировок.

Answer (score 0):

Ну, конечно, было бы красивее разъяснить, кто такой этот регистрируемый, но и так, как есть у Вас, допустимо.